# How to search, count, and save words?

Tags: python

I am trying to identify a particular word and then count it. I need to save the count for each identifier.

For example,

> risk risk risk free interest rate
>
> asterisk risk risk
>
> market risk risk [risk

*A document contains words above and I need to count 'risk' not asterisk. I also need to count [risk as 'risk'. Here is what I have so far. However, it returns a count for asterisk and [risk as well as risk. I don't need a count for asterisk, but only for risk including [risk. I tried to use regular expression but keep getting errors. Plus, I am a beginner of Python. If anyone has any idea, please help me!!^^ Thanks.

```
from collections import defaultdict
word_dict = defaultdict(int)

for line in mylist:
words = line.lower().split()
for word in words:
    word_dict[word]+=1

for word in word_dict:
if 'risk' in word:
    word, word_dict[word]
```

Answer (score 2):

Give a regex another go. Match the string `'risk'` surrounded by word boundaries

```
import re
re.findall(r'\brisk\b', 'risk risk') ## 2 matches
re.findall(r'\brisk\b', 'risk risk riskrisk') ## 2 matches
re.findall(r'\brisk\b', 'risk risk riskrisk [risk') ## 3 matches
re.findall(r'\brisk\b', 'risk risk riskrisk [risk asterisk') ## 3 matches
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a pipelined approach. By that I mean, before you add the word to the dictionary, perform any transformations on the text so the counts are correct.

```
word_dict = {} # empty dictionary

for line in mylist:
    words = line.strip().lower().split() # the strip gets rid of new lines
    for word in words:
        # the strip here will strip away any surrounding punctuation.
        # add any other symbols to the string that you need
        # the key insight here, is you get rid of extra stuff BEFORE inserting
        # into the dictionary
        word_dict[word.strip('[/@#$%')]+=1 

for word in word_dict:
    print word, word_dict[word]

# to just see the count for risk:
print word_dict['risk']
```

The fact that it counts the word "asterisk", is fine, as long as you counted your word "risk".

Answer (score 0):

You can try this snippet:

```
import shlex

words = shlex.split("risk risk risk free interest rate")
word_count = len([word for word in words if word == "risk" or word =="[risk"])
print word_count
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define more rigorously what criteria counts for `risk` and what doesn't.  However, I would use a `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()
with open(yourfile) as f:
    for line in f:
        c += Counter(line.split())
```

Now at this point, you need create a function which will figure out whether it should count as 'risk' or not:

```
def is_risk(word):
    w = word.lower()
    return 'risk' in w and w!='asterisk'
```

Now just add the elements corresponding to those keys:

```
sum( c[k] for k in c if is_risk(k) )
```

Answer (score -2):

so you count

```
'\n' + risk + '\n'
'\n' + risk + ' '
' ' + risk + '\n'
' ' + risk + ' '
```